# Remove header and footer export data from CSV to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to export data from CSV to SQL Server

My CSV file is like this

```
Name,CustomerID
A,1 
b,2
End
```

I need to export only the data into the SQL Server table

```
A,1
b,2
```

I tried to work with `BULK INSERT`, but header is coming

I need to remove header and footer.

Is the only option is to create a bcp with format file

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use first_row and last_row options. If there are 100 rows set first_row=2 and last_row=99

Comment: how to get the number of records in csv.Thanks. with firstrow i can remove the header